# How to open a new text file in buffer using total number of buffer in neovim?

Tags: lua, buffer, neovim, key-bindings

I want to make a keymap for `<F7>` in neovim such that if the current file is a text file then a new file will open horizontally but the file name will depend on the total number of buffer.
Ex: Now open files are `inp1.txt`, `inp2.txt` in buffer. And total number of buffer is 2. If I press `<F7>` a new file `inp3.txt` will open horizontally. How can I do this in my neovim lua config file? Here all files have `inp` and `.txt`. Just change the number.

I want to make something like cph (vs code extension) for competitive programming. I use tmux. I open the `cpp` file in the left side in a tmux pane and in the the other right side pane I want to open some `txt` file horizontally to contain the input. But I want to open a `txt` file quickly. I want to do it using  key.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't understand how can I put 1,2,3,4... with the inp().txt. I don't know lua language.

Comment: If you don't know Lua, why do you want to have a Lua solution?

Comment: I just want to change the number of the text file. I don't know this. I think I will understand the solution because I have some knowledge about lua as I am a neovim user.

Answer (score 1):

Considering Neovim still supports vanilla VimScript, this should do it:

```
noremap <F7> :execute ":new inp" .. (bufnr('$') + 1) .. ".txt"<CR>
```

A bit more complex solution to account only existing buffers:

```
noremap <F7> :execute ":new inp" .. (len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')) + 1) .. ".txt"<CR>
```

Comment: can I store this value in a variable

Comment: New buffer name?

Comment: Maybe use `noremap` rather than `map`? And it's worth mentioning "that not all buffers with a smaller number necessarily exist" (from `:help bufnr()`). And why edit the vim tag out of the question to give a pure vim answer?

Comment: @Friedrich Good point, fixed. As for non existing buffers: even if a smaller buffer number is vacant, OP does not request it to be reused. The question targets neovim, but the answer is hopefully applicable to both vim and neovim.

Comment: I was rather thinking that skipping numbers (especially when a lot of other buffers were opened and closed) might lead to surprises. I don't see any issues with your answer (that's why I upvoted), I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: I agree, checking for buffers to exist makes sense. I updated the answer.

Comment: How can I store the number of buffer in a variable? Again if I want to store the number of buffer in a file for ex - !echo (len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')) + 1) > a.txt will not exist.

Comment: For example `noremap <F7> :let myvar = len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')) + 1 \| execute ":new inp" .. myvar .. ".txt"<CR>`. Then `:echo myvar`.

Comment: :let a=(len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')) + 1) may be ok. But how to write this in lua? will local a = (len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')) + 1) work?

Comment: Chatgpt gives this answer -

Comment: vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<F7>', [[
    let myvar = len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')) + 1
    execute ":new inp" .. myvar .. ".txt"
]], { noremap = true, silent = true })

Comment: I'm not familiar with neovim lua api, but try `local a = vim.api.nvim_eval('len(filter(range(1, bufnr("$")), "bufexists(v:val)")) + 1')`

Comment: Please do not ask to debug ChatGPT nonsense.

Comment: I got my solution. Chatgpt was wrong. Thank you again. Your solution works fine.

Comment: @syedtamal if this answers your question, consider accepting the answer using the v-shaped button to its left. This is how we say "thank you" on SO :)